# Increasing values of elements in list

Tags: c++, list, element

I need help increasing the values of elements in mylist and assigning that new list to mylist3. I tried doing it as you would an array or vector but it did not work. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
std::list<int> mylist(myarray, myarray + sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(int));
cout << "mylist contains: ";
for (std::list<int>::iterator b = mylist.begin(); b != mylist.end(); ++b)
    cout << ' ' << *b;

cout << "\n" << endl;

std::list<int> mylist3(10);
for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    mylist3[z] = mylist[z] + 5;
}

cout << "mylist3 contains: ";
for (std::list<int>::iterator f = mylist3.begin(); f != mylist3.end(); ++f)
    cout << ' ' << *f;
```

Comment: Is there any reason for foregoing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or even proper formatting?

Comment: So you used iterators to print the contents of the list, but you couldn't use them to modify the list?

Comment: You cannot access list elements by index, since a list is not a random-access container. You have to traverse the list and act on sequential elements.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a list? Can't you just go for a vector?

Answer (score 6):

Easily done with the standard library:

```
std::transform(mylist.begin(),mylist.end(),std::back_inserter(mylist3),
    [](int i){return i+5;});
```

Comment: yes, use splice to produce a list from another list or apply std::transform if custom operation has to be done on elements

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing this fairly readably:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>


std::list<int> mylist(std::begin(myarray), std::end(myarray)), mylist3 = mylist;

for (int & n : mylist3)
    n += 5;

std::cout << "mylist3 contains:";
for (int n : mylist3)
    std::cout << ' ' << n;
std::cout << '\n';
```